# Grails run-app fails on VM VirtualBox: hangs on build, can't access server

Tags: linux, grails, networking, virtualbox

I'm new to Grails and attempting to implement the Hello World app described at grails.org's Getting Started guide.

I have installed Grails using SDKman on an Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM (VirtualBox, running as a service). My host machine is Windows 10.

I configured two network adapters in VirtualBox: the first a NAT with port forwarding (3022 host -> 22 guest, 8080 host -> 8080 guest), the second a Host-Only adapter.

I can SSH into my VM just fine from my Windows host (using Bash): `ssh -p 3022 user@localhost`

When I run `python3 -m http.server 8080` from that SSH session, it successfully listens on both localhost:8080 and :8080. I can access both URLs from a browser on my host machine.

When I run `grails run-app` it hangs forever, and none of the above endpoints work from my host.

When I run `grails run-app --verbose` I see it compile without complaint through "Building 85% > :bootRun". I understand that this is [expected behavior](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/641), but I never see "Application started" or any similar message. It never starts.

ONE TIME the following command succeeded in building and running the app, creating exactly the result I needed:
`grails -Dserver.port=8080 -Dserver.host=0.0.0.0 run-app --verbose --stacktrace`

However when I stopped the app and tried again, it failed as before.

I notice that VirtualBox > Settings > Network > Adapter #2 which I had set as "Host-Only Network" has multiple times *reset* itself to Bridged. I suspect that this reset may have caused my problem. But I don't know how to prevent the reset, or to restore that functionality I so briefly had.

Thanks, anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved! Turns out run-app just takes a LONG time to finish compiling and building, upwards of 10 minutes. So I just needed to wait ~5+ minutes with no visual sign of action before the completion message would show and I could access my site. :)

Comment: VirtualBox can be a bit slow, just run your app locally (Windows, OSX, Linux). You do not need to install tomcat or anything, just Grails

Comment: The slowness came from my using VirtualBox shared folders to store the Grails files. Unnecessary! I moved the project to a virtual-machine-only folder and added Sublime SFTP to my Windows IDE to do my text editing 'remotely'. Builds in <1 minute now.